# Building libconfig 64bit on Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos, compilation, 64-bit, libconfig

I would like to build and install [libconfig](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/) as 64-bit on my Mac OS X (v10.8.3).
Which are the commands that I could use inside the terminal?
If I simply use `./configure` and `sudo make install` the library will be installed as 32-bit.

Otherwise... How can I correctly remove the library from my system after installation process (library is in `/usr/local/` path)?

Kind regards, Vi.

Comment: You can do a `make uninstall` in the project directory. I encountered the same problem with the 32bit version. This seems (at first sight and googleing) be related to the output of `uname -p`, which is i386. Don't ask me why, sadly I do not know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to pass `CFLAGS='-arch x86_64'` on the configure command line to set the architecture correctly:

```
./configure CFLAGS='-arch x86_64'
```

**Update:**

Adding `CFLAGS` doesn't change how configure detects the system, it just changes what gets passed to `gcc`.  But it will build as a 64-bit executable:

```
$ file lib/.libs/libconfig.*.dylib
lib/.libs/libconfig.9.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

If you really want the `configure` output to be correct, then you need to pass in a `--build` parameter:

```
$ ./configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0
...
```

The resultant library is also 64-bit:

```
$ file lib/.libs/libconfig.*.dylib
lib/.libs/libconfig.9.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

Admittedly, using the `--build` option is the better choice here.  However, since gcc on Mac OS X can build "fat" binaries, it kind of blurs the line a little about what machine you're building for, since it can build for both i386 and x86_64.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help, as passing arch flags to C or CXX does not influence the detection of the `configure` call. Configure spits out: `checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin12.4.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin12.4.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin12.4.0`

Comment: @MarioMueller Changing `CFLAGS` doesn't change how configure recognizes the system.  I updated my answer with more information, and an alternate way, if you want configure's detection to be correct.